Equation relating the current carried by a solenoid to the force experienced by a magnetic dipole?
I am trying to find an equation or a series of equations that relates the current I carried by a solenoid of length L with turns N to the force F experienced by a magnetic dipole of strength M that rests at a distance d from the solenoid so that they are both aligned along their central axes.
Specifically, I am trying to model this scenario inside of matlab, so it would be helpful if the answer could be expressed in such a way that differential equations are avoided. For example, I saw answers on other forums that simply stated that F = M dB/dx, but this isnt very helpful for me because the shape of the magnetic field is hard to model in matlab like that, as far as I know.
Thanks!
EDIT:
I have found this equation in another forum, but I cant exactly decipher what z1 and z2 are supposed to be, if someone could identify them for me that would be great.

